# python json.loads() failed when value is a json string

Tags: python, json

env: python 2.7

When I read data from db, the value is`{"key": "{\"subKey\":\"subValue\"}"}`. I want to convert it to json, the code is:

```
import json

def readValueFromDb():
  return '{"key": "{\"subKey\":\"subValue\"}"}'

jsonObject = json.loads(readValueFromDb())
```

But there occurs exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting , delimiter: line 1 column 12 (char 11)
```

I find there no difference between `{"key": "{\"subKey\":\"subValue\"}"}` and `{"key": "{"subKey":"subValue"}"}`.

By the way, the value is a variable so I can't change it to raw string as I find it works fine like this:

```
import json

jsonObject = json.loads(r'{"key": "{\"subKey\":\"subValue\"}"}')
```

So, what should I do if I want to convert the value to json?

And I tried to replace `'\"'` to `'\\"'`, but can find no `'\"'`. Strange.

Comment: your backslashes are swallowed up by python. are you sure they come from the db this way?

Comment: Could you show `print repr(value)` when value comes from the database? Because the backslashes (`\ `) are ignored in your code...

Comment: I tried, but the code was build in a saas, and it does't support `print()` in the log. But I'm sure, the data in db is just like `{"key": "{\"subKey\":\"subValue\"}"}`. And the type is  `varchar`.

Comment: Perhaps, use logging to debug, and try some of approaches mentioned before.

Comment: Sorry, but debug is not allowed as well. So I have to copy the value from db, and test it. And the same exception occurs.

Comment: This is a big ugly bad solution, but what about use replace `'{"key": "{\"subKey\":\"subValue\"}"}'.replace('"', "'").replace("\'", '"')`?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: have you even tried that? it's a no-op.

Comment: @MonkeyKing: you have to understand what the difference between the content of a string and the representation of a string is, as well as how escaping in python strings works. `"foo\"bar" == 'foo"bar'` and both strings have only 7 characters. if what you gave as an example is really what you get from the database, you data is already broken and probably unusable without manual work. i vote to close.

Comment: @hop you're right :-|

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the database is as you describe, then your code example should look like:

```
import json

def readValueFromDb():
    return '{"key": "{\\"subKey\\":\\"subValue\\"}"}'

jsonObject = json.loads(readValueFromDb())
```

And your object looks like:

```
print(jsonObject)
{u'key': u'{"subKey":"subValue"}'}
```

Now, the inside JSON document can be parsed.

There is no "raw string", there are just "raw string literals". It's a way of representing strings in code. If you do (with my version from above):

```
print(readValueFromDb())
{"key": "{\"subKey\":\"subValue\"}"}
```

then you get exactly what you claim to be in the database.

And just on a tangent, why isn't the data in your database actually like this:

```
{"key": {"subKey": "subValue"}}
```

This is a much more logical way of storing a JSON object.